# HTML Form & Godaddy PHP

Tags: forms

Trying to set up a form in HTML & PHP & then use it on go daddy but it's not working. I'm VERY new when it comes to PHP. I'm sure my code needs more than what I have. What am I not doing or missing? like I said I'm new to .PHP. Whatever help I can get will be very appreciated.

here's the HTML form code:

```
<form id="ApplicantForm" action="gdform.php" method="post" >


<div class="formname">First Name<br><input name="first Name" type="text" id="first Name" title="First Name" size="10"></div>

<div class="formname">M.I.<br><input name="MI" type="text" id="MI" title="Middle Initial" size="2" maxlength="1"></div>

<div class="formname">Last <br><input name="Last" type="text" required id="Last" title="Last Name" size="10"></div>

<div class="formname">Suffix<br><select>
  <option selected>I</option>
  <option>II</option>
  <option>III</option>
  <option>IV</option>
  <option>Jr.</option>
  <option>Sr.</option>
</select></div>
<br>
<div class="formInfo">email <br><input name="email" type="text" id="emailAddr" title="email" size="40"></div><br>
<div class="formInfo">Address <br><input name="address" type="text" required id="Addr1" title="Address" size="40"></div><br>
<div class="formInfo">City <br><input name="City" type="text" required id="AddrCity" title="City" size="40"></div><br>
<div class="formInfo">State <br><input name="State" type="text" required id="AddrState" title="State" size="40"></div><br>
<div class="formInfo">Zip Code<br><input name="Zip" type="text" required id="AddrZip" title="Zip" size="20"></div>

<div class="formInfo">Country<br><input name="Country" type="text" required id="country" title="Country" size="20"></div>
<br><br>
<div class="formQues">I wish to keep my contact Information confidential <br>

    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="KeepInfoConfidential1" value="InfoConfidential"  id="InfConfidential1_0">
      Yes</label>

    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="KeepInfoConfidential1" value="InfoConfidential" id="InfConfidential1_1">
      No</label>
    </div><br>
    <div class="PhoneInfo">Phone Number<br><input name="PhoneNumber" type="text" required id="PhoneNo" title="Phone Number" size="15"></div>

    <div class="PhoneInfo"><br>
   <select name="PhoneNumber" id="PhoneNumber" title="PhoneNumber">
     <option>Mobile</option>
     <option>Home</option>
     <option>Fax</option>
   </select> 
   </div>
    <div class="PhoneInfo">Alt Number<br><input name="AlternateNumber" type="text" id="AltNo" title="Alternate Number" size="15"></div><div class="PhoneInfo"><br>
   <select name="AlternateNumber" id="AlternateNumber" title="AlternateNumber">
     <option>Mobile</option>
     <option>Home</option>
     <option>Fax</option>
   </select> 
   </div><br>


<div class="formQues">I wish to keep my Phone Numbers confidential <br>

    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="KeepNumbersConfidential1" value="NumbersConfidential"  id="KeepNumbConf">
      Yes</label>

    <label>
      <input name="KeepNumbersConfidential1" type="radio" id="KeepNumbConf2" value="NumbersConfidential" checked>
      No</label>
    </div><br>
<div class="BestTime">Best time of the day to reach you<br>
   <select required>
     <option>Morning</option>
     <option>Mid Day</option>
     <option>Evening</option>
   </select> </div><br>

   <div class="formQues">I will require Visa Sponsorship <br>

    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="VisaSpon1" value="VisaSponsorship"  id="VisaSpons1">
      Yes</label>

    <label>
      <input name="VisaSpon1" type="radio" id="VisaSpons2" value="VisaSponsorship" checked>
      No</label>
    </div><br>

 <div class="formQues">Are You Willing To Relocate? <br>

    <label>
      <input name="relocate" type="radio"  id="WillingToRelocate1" value="WillYouRelocate" checked>
      Yes</label>

    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="relocate" value="WillYouRelocate" id="WillingToRelocate2">
      No</label>
    </div>   <br>

 <div class="BestTime">Type of facility you desire/willing to work<br>
   <select name="DesiredFacility"  required id="DesiredFacility" title="Desired Facility">
     <option>Private Physician Office</option>
     <option>Hospital</option>
     <option>Long Term Care/Nursing Home</option>
     <option>Community Centers (i.e. CVS, Walgreens, Little Clinic)</option>
   </select> 
   </div> <br>  

   <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" title="Submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
```

here's the PHP code:

```
<?php
    $request_method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
    if($request_method == "GET"){
      $query_vars = $_GET;
    } elseif ($request_method == "POST"){
      $query_vars = $_POST;
    }
    reset($query_vars);
    $t = date("U");

    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/../data/gdform_" . $t;
    $fp = fopen($file,"w");
    while (list ($key, $val) = each ($query_vars)) {
     fputs($fp,"<GDFORM_VARIABLE NAME=$key START>\n");
     fputs($fp,"$val\n");
     fputs($fp,"<GDFORM_VARIABLE NAME=$key END>\n");
     if ($key == "redirect") { $landing_page = $val;}
    }
    fclose($fp);
    if ($landing_page != ""){
    header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/$landing_page");
    } else {
    header("Location: http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/");
    }

$to = "myNAme@yahoo.com";
?>
```

Comment: exactly what is wrong with this code? We're not going to read through a wall of the stuff to try and GUESS what the problems are.

Comment: Oh no... Sorry... I left to much in there... the only part on the  <form> portion that's important is the first line. The rest isn't important.

Comment: that still doesn't explain **HOW** it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is in your while-function. This section specificly:

```
$fp = fopen($file,"w");
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($query_vars)) {
 fputs($fp,"<GDFORM_VARIABLE NAME=$key START>\n");
 fputs($fp,"$val\n");
 fputs($fp,"<GDFORM_VARIABLE NAME=$key END>\n");
 if ($key == "redirect") { $landing_page = $val;}
}
fclose($fp);
```

Looks a lot more like c++ coding to me?

Regardless, what i would recommend is rewriting that section to something like this instead:

```
$output = "";
foreach($query_vars as $key => $value){
  $output .= "<GDFORM_VARIABLE NAME=" . $key. " START>\n" . $val . "\n<GDFORM_VARIABLE NAME=" . $key . " END>\n";
}
file_put_contents($file, $output);
```

This would cut out the need to open and close the file seperately, and simply leave it all to "file_put_contents()" to handle that.

Additionally, i'm not entirely sure if $query_vars are out-of-scope somehow. To be safe, i would rewrite:

```
$request_method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
if($request_method == "GET"){
  $query_vars = $_GET;
} elseif ($request_method == "POST"){
  $query_vars = $_POST;
}
```

into:

```
$query_vars = ($request_method == "GET" ? $_GET : $_POST);
```

Additionally, the way you're doing it, using:

```
reset($query_vars);
```

is not required.

For future reference, php have excellent error-reporting. Simply add this to the top of your file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and just run the page. You should be able to work out the issues from that.